# Matrix Transpose Common Lisp

Tags: recursion, common-lisp, transpose

Well, i've been told to make a Matrix Transpose function in common lisp. I'm a beginner, so i don't know so much of it.

My Matrix is a list of lists, and i can't use apply, mapcar or similar to solve it, just CONS, CAR and CDR. If not, my solution would be this (I put this solution so someone can use it):

```
(DEFUN transpose (List)
    (apply #'mapcar #'list List)
)
```

But I can't use anything of the above.

The function has to be recursive, no loops or similar.

So, the question is, how could this be done?

This is how far i've gone, but it gets me an overflow error. I don't really know how to do it (i could have done it in C++ or Java, but i'm asked to do it in Lisp...)

```
    (DEFUN transpose (Matrix)
        (COND   ((NULL Matrix) NIL
                ) 
                (T (CONS (CAR(CAR Matrix))(transpose (CONS (CAR(CDR Matrix)) (CDR Matrix))))
                )
        )
    )
```

Any help would be thanked!

Comment: Why the limitations?

Comment: Just because the teacher tolds. I don't understand the limitations

Comment: Odd requirement. I'd think that allowing a beginner to make use of the fundamental functions of a language would be a good thing.

Comment: Whoops, I originally read that you *couldn't* use CONS, CAR or CDR. My bad. This assignment makes more sense now.

Comment: This sort of limitation is done in an attempt to teach recursion. It's entirely the wrong way to teach, but unfortunately universities have a fetish for misteaching lisp to the point that a lot of people absolutely hate the language because they've been subjected to such a bad style. It totally makes sense when teaching scheme in the 70's, absolutely not in 2016.

Comment: Now if a teacher wanted you to understand what (apply #'mapcar #'list list) does, they would make you implement MAPCAR and LIST and teach abstraction rather than the way they used to do in on PDP-10's with caddaddaders everywhere.

Comment: Are you allowed to define your own helper functions? If do, a judicious `(defun my-list (&rest args) args)` would not go amiss...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a simple solution that does not use iteration or high-order functions.

```
(defun cars (matrix)
  "Return a list with all the cars of the lists in matrix"
  (if (null matrix)
      nil
      (cons (car (car matrix)) (cars (cdr matrix)))))

(defun cdrs (matrix)
  "Return a list with all the cdrs of the lists in matrix"
  (if (null matrix)
      nil
      (cons (cdr (car matrix)) (cdrs (cdr matrix)))))

(defun transpose (matrix)
  "Transpose matrix"
  (cond ((null matrix) nil)
        ((null (car matrix)) nil)
        (t (cons (cars matrix) (transpose (cdrs matrix))))))
```

The function `transpose` uses two auxiliary functions: `cars` returns a list with all the first elements of the lists representing the matrix, while `cdrs` returns a list with all the remaining parts of the lists representing the matrix, so we can use the recursion.

`cars` works by applying recursively `car` to all the elements of the lists (that are lists), and returns a list obtained by “consing” them; `cdrs` works in the same way, this time applying `cdr` instead of `car`.

Comment: Now I see what i have to do, i'd never get to that solution