# A safe way to transpose a list of of lists in lisp?

Tags: common-lisp

Transposing a list of lists is easy but comes with a caveat that you must not exceed the `call-arguments-limit`.

http://www.lispworks.com/kb/4fbc798cb17237ca852566da005fcc79.html

What's a safe way to write transpose for when the length of the lists may exceed `call-arguments-limit`?

For example, the answer is not this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3513158/914859

```
(defun transpose (list-of-lists)
  (apply #'mapcar #'list list-of-lists))
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39943232/matrix-transpose-common-lisp what about that

Answer (score 6):

Here is a non-recursive version unencumbered
by [`call-arguments-limit`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_call_a.htm) et al:

```
(defun pop-all (list-of-lists)
  "Pop each list in the list, return list of pop results
and an indicator if some list has been exhausted."
  (loop for tail on list-of-lists collect (pop (car tail))))

(defun transpose (list-of-lists)
  "Transpose the matrix."
  (loop with tails = (copy-list list-of-lists)
    while (some #'consp tails) ; or any?
    collect (pop-all tails)))
```

Test:

```
(defparameter ll '((1 4 7) (2 5 8) (3 6 9)))
(transpose ll)
==> ((1 2 3) (4 5 6) (7 8 9))
ll
==> ((1 4 7) (2 5 8) (3 6 9))
(equal ll (transpose (transpose ll)))
==> T
```

Note that I scan `list-of-lists` *twice* per iteration - once in `some` and once in `pop-all` (same as in the [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39943764/850781)).

We can avoid it with a little extra work:

```
(defun pop-all (list-of-lists)
  "Pop each list in the list, return list of pop results
and an indicator if some list has been exhausted."
  (loop for tail on list-of-lists
    for more = (consp (car tail)) then (and more (consp (car tail)))
    collect (pop (car tail)) into card
    finally (return (values cars more))))

(defun transpose (list-of-lists)
  "Transpose the matrix."
  (loop with tails = (copy-list list-of-lists) and more and cars
    do (setf (values cars more) (pop-all tails))
    while more collect cars))
```